# How to integrate webkit into a C++ Windows application

Tags: c++, windows, webkit

I've downloaded a [nightly build](http://nightly.webkit.org/) of webkit which includes a dll, pdb. There are no header files and I can't find documentation on the API and usage of the dll.

I'm looking for example code to integrate this into a C++ application, and how to start requests, render them to window or ideally a Direct X texture.

So far my searching is coming up short on the webkit website and the internet at large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you use `QWebKit` from Qt? see [this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtwebkit.html)

Comment: +1 for QWebkit, if you can swallow the Qt dependency, it makes things real easy.

Answer (score 12):

You might want to check out the Chromium Embedded Framework available here: http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/

I've used it extensively and found it to be functional, stable, and easy to use.  It is smaller than QWebKit and has a more liberal license.